# Git Detached Head in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, git-detached-head

I am using Git with Flutter and recently I noted that doing a commit I get the message about a Detached Head. I would like to remove the detached head situation.

This was probably generated by the fact that I moved back from version 6.3.1 non-nullable that created some coding issues to a previous "nullable" version.

Then I did some modifications and some commits.

Now I would keep the current version (6.5.0) merging back and removing the detached head status but without going again in the non-nullable version 6.3.1.

How can I do (I use the user interface of Git for Android Studio)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried merging that loose-ends branch into your current head?  There may be conflicts, but hopefully they'll all resolve correctly.

Comment: You could also try rebasing 6.4.2 onto your loose branch.  That might also have conflicts, but at least you'd end up with a nice linear history.

Comment: I haven't tried. Which commands should I use to do that? (I am a beginner)

Comment: git checkout 6.5.0 , then git rebase 6.3.1 non nullable, then resolve the conflicts.

Comment: How can I do git rebase 6.3.1 non-nullable? I do not see anything similar in the menu in the picture. Also, I need to pay attention to not restore anything in 6.3.1 non-nullable version since that one was causing issues. Is this action correct?

Comment: I don't know what IDE you're using.  I only know the command-line args for this.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
git checkout <branch name> 

Or

git checkout -
```

But you may lose your work. You can try

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

And merge it to the master and use the master branch

Comment: which of the 2? the second I guess...

Comment: Second wil let you keep your works on a different branch and you can merge it with the master.